# Trying to make this loop documentwriteln properly, can't break lines and don't know how to number

Tags: javascript

This is what I've got so far. I'm trying to get this to print vertically (A line in the HTML for every single output from the loop), and have a respective integer attached to each. So just like this:

```
1. 638.33299939824
2. 648.23949999302
3. 649.19290102884
etc....etc...etc..
```

Right now it just prints like this:

```
638.33299939824 648.23949999302 649.19290102884 etc.. etc... etc..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
document.writeln(swag)
```

With:

```
document.writeln((i+1) + '. ' + swag + '<br />');
```

I'm using `i+1`, since `i` starts counting at `0`, but it seems like you want it to count from `1`, in the html.

Comment: But, the hell, why are you so fast?

Comment: That, young apprentice, is the master's secret ;-).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I really appreciate it. However, it doesn't seem to be working. The output appears the same but rather there's just a 1. at the beginning of the first output and no line breaks... Do you have any tips?

Comment: @Cerbrus I edited my reply, it was an accidental submit D: I'm experiencing some issues

Comment: Eh, can you make a screenshot of the result?

Comment: But, the hell, why did you forget a small thing?

Comment: Shouldn't it be <br/>'?

Comment: nicael: a typo is no reason for a extra answer. You should just have suggested an edit, instead. @Saimouer: since it appears to work for you, could you consider accepting this answer?

Comment: Agree, ok. But how didn't you noticed it yourself? Master's secret?